# C - passing arrays through functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have the following...

```
void keySorter(char (*keys)[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys]) {}

int main ()
{
  char keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys] = {};
  keySorter (&keys);
}
```

So, I have this, it compiles fine, but I'm getting back what I want. The keys[][] has been initialized with `= {};` so it's empty, but it's supposed to get filled with stuff once inside the function.

The first element gets placed into the function the rest goes...? I watch the function STRCPY which puts the data into keys[][] and its has the right source value the destination value seems to be garbage though (or at least it made up characters that look like garbage).

```
strcpy(*keys[i], "BLAH");
```

That's the other part of the function.

Comment: How are you trying to read the values inside keySorter?

Comment: Also, have you populated `keys`?

Comment: No, I'm actually trying to fill the keys[][]. Its sent in empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is (C99) code that works - the output is tidy if your window is more than 100 columns wide (adjust the 32 to a smaller number if you have narrow windows):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { NumberOfKeys = 20, LengthOfKeys = 32 };

static void keySorter(char (*keys)[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys])
{
    size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NumberOfKeys; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < LengthOfKeys; j++)
            (*keys)[i][j] = ++k & 0xFF;
}

static void dumpKeys(char keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NumberOfKeys; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < LengthOfKeys; j++)
            printf("%02X ", keys[i][j] & 0xFF);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys] = {};
    printf("Before:\n");
    dumpKeys(keys);
    keySorter(&keys);
    printf("After:\n");
    dumpKeys(keys);
}
```

Notice the crucial difference between the notations used to access the array in `keySorter()` compared to `dumpKeys()`.   In the first, because a pointer to a 2D array is passed, the code to access the array must first dereference the pointer with `(*keys)[i][j]`, whereas in the second, the array is passed directly and the direct access notation `keys[i][j]` is fine.

When I compiled with (GCC 4.2.1 on MacOS X 10.6.5) using:

```
gcc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition xx.c -o xx
```

the code shown compiles cleanly.  When I experimented with using `keys[i][j]` in `keySorter()`, it complained 'error: incompatible types in assignment`.

You can also revise the `keySorter()` to use `strcpy()` (you should `#include <string.h>` too, of course):

```
static void keySorter(char (*keys)[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NumberOfKeys; i++)
        strcpy((*keys)[i], "BLAH");
}
```

You still have to dereference the pointer to the array before indexing into the array.

If/when you wrote:

```
strcpy(keys[i], "BLAH");
```

then you should be getting compiler warnings (if you aren't get a better compiler, or at the very least, work out how to make your compiler emit copious warnings), but the value of `keys[0]` was the first array in the set of arrays pointed to by `keys`, and then `keys[1]` was the second array, and `keys[2]` was the third array, and so on.  The pointer might decay enough that you end up writing BLAH over the first row of each array, but you'll end up with a core dump or other such problems because you didn't allocate enough arrays in the main program.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `keySorter`, `keys` is a pointer to an array of arrays of `char`. This means that to get an array of `char` for use with `strcpy` you need to derefence the pointer, then use array access to select an array.

E.g.

```
strcpy((*keys)[i], "test");
```

You can't use `*keys[i]` because the precedence rules mean that `[]` is applied first and `keys` is not a pointer to the first element of an array it is a pointer to the array itself.

Incidentally, for what you are doing it is much more conventional to declare `keySorter` as taking a pointer to an array of chars and let the normal array to pointer decay happen on arguments to the function.

```
void keySorter(char keys[][LengthOfKeys]);
```

or

```
void keySorter(char (*keys)[LengthOfKeys]);
```

In this case you can simply do `strcpy(keys[i], "blah")` because `keys` is a pointer *into* an array of arrays of `char`.

Called:

```
int main ()
{
  char keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys] = {};
  keySorter(keys);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare the auto variable `keys` but don't put anything into it, so it will contain garbage values.

Yes, you are pasing the array correctly, in that the call and the declared function parameter type match. But you are passing a *pointer to an array of an array of char* instead of a simple pointer to the array's first *char* element. Perhaps you should do it this way:

```
void keySorter(char keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys])
{...}

int main(void)
{
    char  keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys];
    keySorter(keys);
}
```

This allows you to access the array elements very simply:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < NumberOfKeys;  i++)
{
    for (int j = 0;  j < LengthOfKeys;  j++)
    {
        ... keys[i][j] ...
    }
}
```

**Addendum**

Adding an explicit initializer value is sufficient to initialize the array to all zeros (i.e., all `'\0'` char values):

```
    char  keys[NumberOfKeys][LengthOfKeys] = { 0 };
```

Comment: `keys` is initialized with zeroes.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: This is C, technically a pair of empty braces isn't a valid initializer.

Comment: @Charles: OK, well, it doesn't compile then (or compiles with a diagnostic and does something implementation-specific). But it probably doesn't leave it as garbage :-)

Answer (score 0):

keys is already a pointer so you dont have to do this keySorter (&keys); put just keySorter (keys);

Comment: `key` by itself is the wrong type, a *pointer to char*, but the function expects a *pointer to array of array of char*.

Comment: @Loadmaster: no it is an two dimensional array of `char` that decays to a `pointer to array of char`. So the syntax of the OP and of this answer here are both correct.

Comment: The syntax in the question is correct, the syntax in this answer is *not* correct. `&keys` is a pointer to an array of arrays of `char` (as expected by the function) but `keys` decays to a pointer to an array of `char` (the first element of an array of array `char`).

Comment: @Charles Bailey: You are correct, and that is exactly what I meant to say.